# Accessing registered file module data using Ansible loops

Tags: ansible

I've tried finding a solution to this in the [Ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-nested-with-cartesian) as well as on Stackoverflow and other sites and blogs.
I've also used debug output of the registered data structures and confirmed I could reach the data when statically referencing it. Lastly I've played with nested loops to try and work out the trick.

The relevant Ansible plays:

```
- name: Return the list of application folders
  win_find:
    paths:
    - C:\Applications\
    patterns: [ 'app*' ]
    file_type: directory
  register: app_folders

- name: Return the list of rotated log files to purge
  win_find:
    paths: 
    - "{{ item.path }}\\logs"
    patterns: applog-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\.\d{2}
    use_regex: yes
  loop: "{{ app_folders.files }}"
  register: logs_to_purge

- name: Purge rotated log files
  win_file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    state: absent
  #loop: "{{ logs_to_purge.results }}"
  #with_nested: 
  #- "{{ logs_to_purge.results }}"
  #- ['files']
```

Results is a list of dict items, some items are normal dict name value pairs, some item values are dicts themselves and some item values are lists of other normal dict item name value pairs.

The data I'm trying to loop through can be represented like this:

```
"logs_to_purge": {
    results:[
                { 
                    "name": value,
                    "name2": value2,
                    "name3": {    }
                    "files": [{
                                  "filevalue1": value,
                                  "filevalue2": value,
                                  "path": value_of_interest 
                              },
                              {
                                  "filevalue1": value,
                                  "filevalue2": value,
                                  "path": value_of_interest
                              }
                            ]

                  },
                  {
                      One more like above for every "app_folders"
                      with zero or more files matches.
                  }
            ]
```

So "results" is a list of dicts. Each results dict contains a dict item "files" which has a list of dicts as value. Each of those dicts contains a "path" item which is the value of interest.

The commented out last four lines of my "Purge rotated log files" Ansible Play above are where I've spent a great many hours to no avail.

Comment: You should check JSON and fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use json_query. The task below

```
- debug:
    var: item
  loop: "{{ logs_to_purge.results|json_query('[*].files[*].path')|flatten }}"
```

gives

```
"item": "value_of_interest"
"item": "value_of_interest"
```